# Set combo box to doc variable on userform vba word

Tags: vba, ms-word, combobox, userform

How can I update my code below so instead of setting the combo box to "bmextension", I would set it to a Variable with the same name. I'd imagine something like Set ComboBox2 = ActiveDocument.Variables("bmextension").Range

```
    Dim ComboBox2 As Range
    Set ComboBox2 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bmextension").Range
    ComboBox2.Text = Me.ComboBox2.Value

    If Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Yes" Then
    ComboBox2.Text = "Please enter your code"
    
    End If
    
    If Me.ComboBox2.Value = "No" Then
    ComboBox2.Text = ""
    
    End If
```

Comment: See [documentation of document variables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-store-and-retrieve-variables-in-word-documents-3a912a35-42a0-7a28-7f2d-787ed6afb566)

Comment: Hey @TimothyRylatt thanks for sharing. However I am still confused on how this would work in conjunction with a combo box. For example my combo box has the items "yes" and "no" in it and when selected it would make the corresponding example text above display in my word document. How do I get the doc variable to work within the framework of a combo box?

Comment: The documentation shows you how to set and retrieve values of a document variable.

Answer (score 0):

See [Word MVP Graham Mayor's page on UserForms](http://www.gmayor.com/Userform.htm) which shows use of bookmarks, document variables and Content Controls.

```
Set ComboBox2 = ActiveDocument.Variables("bmextension").Value
```